# Angular 2 webpack build from UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)

Tags: angular, webpack

I am getting

from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)

error when running npm run build on angular2-webpack

This is coming from a spread operator.

Trying to demo a project in less than 1 hour.... FML

Answer (score -1):

Changing the target from ES6 to ES5 can help. However, I was able to find a more reliable solution to use the advantages of ES6.

Simply specify UglifyJs in your package.json, and let npm handles the dependencies.

`"uglify-js": "git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony-v2.8.22",`